# How to use a CSS class with the jQuery Bootstrap4 effect

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, effect

So i'm using jquery effect to put a highlight in certain situations.   It looks something like this

```
$("#spanAdultCount").effect("highlight", { color: "#008000" }, 3000);
```

I can't figure out how to use a css class instead of the color:"#008000".  can someone tell me what that would look like. I've seen jquery has a css() but i don't know how to apply it to the effect with the hightlight. i don't even know if i'm on the right track.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use addClass() function  for adding class, Please check the fiddle for how to use css() function

```js
$('.click_me').on("click",function(){
    $(this).addClass("highlighted");
});
$('.click_me_1').on("click",function(){
    $(this).css("border","1px solid gold");
});

$('.click_me_effect').on("click",function(){
    $(this).effect( "highlight",{ color: "#008000" },3000,function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
        //Or you can use direct css method
        //$(this).css("border","1px solid gold");
     });
});
```

```css
.click_me, .click_me_1, .click_me_effect {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    width: 225px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.click_me.highlighted, .click_me_effect.highlighted {
    border: 1px solid gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  
<div class="click_me">
Click Me - highlight through class
</div>

<div class="click_me_1">
Click Me - highlight through css()
</div>

<div class="click_me_effect">
 Click Me - highlight through effect and addClass
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that.. it's helpful to a point however I understand what you are saying.  I understand how you can use the addClass in some situations.. but with the effect() and how it requires 2 parts inside the effects, how do you apply a class to the effect()

Comment: i updated the above fiddle. Please check it,  did you mean this ?

Comment: thanks for helping.  no, this isn't what i was wanting.  I tried to add the class as the second parm and the remove the class on completion and that is not working.  I am trying to have the color be controlled by through the scss and not hard coded in.